# Post object error in RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I'm posting object with below code

Models

```
@interface Event : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * eventID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Calendar *calendar; // many-to-one

@interface Calendar : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * calendarID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *events; // one-to-many
```

RKRequestDescriptor

```
RKObjectMapping *calendarRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[calendarRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                             @"calendarID":@"calendar"}];
RKObjectMapping *postRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[postRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"title"]];
[postRequestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"calendar" toKeyPath:@"calendar" withMapping:calendarRequestMapping]];

RKRequestDescriptor * eventRequestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:postRequestMapping objectClass:[Event class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:eventRequestDescriptor];
```

POST

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:event path:@"/events/" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
```

According to the server log, What I posted is

```
{u'calendar[calendar]': [u'3b60a22c-d46e-46ca-b978-ec81a8b47fcb'], u'title': [u'xxxxx']}
```

What I expect is

```
{u'calendar': [u'3b60a22c-d46e-46ca-b978-ec81a8b47fcb'], u'title': [u'xxxxx']}
```

I have tried

```
[calendarRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                             @"calendarID":nil}];
```

Or

```
[postRequestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"calendar" toKeyPath:nil withMapping:calendarRequestMapping]];
```

Both of them will throw an exception.

Comment: The JSON you show isn't valid and needs to be corrected.

Comment: Sorry for confusing here, I just copied the data from my server log, which isn't the raw json format. The problem here is the key of the relationship field `calendar`, what I expected is `calendar` but `calendar[calendar]`

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your attention here:) @Wain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed this issue with below mapping

```
RKObjectMapping *eventRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[eventRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                         @"title":@"title",
                                                         @"calendar.calendarID":@"calendar"}];
```